# Schema validation for anyType element

Tags: xml, visual-studio, serialization, xsd, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to make use of Visual Studio's schema validation while editing some XML files.  The files contain serialized objects for `DataContractSerializer` to read.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyRoot xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyDomain"
        xmlns:lib="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MyList xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:anyType i:type="lib:MyObject">
            <lib:Identifier>my-identifier</lib:Identifier>
            <lib:MyProperty>my-property-value</lib:MyProperty>
        </a:anyType>
        <a:anyType i:type="lib:MyOtherObject">
            <lib:Identifier>my-identifier</lib:Identifier>
            <lib:MyOtherProperty>my-other-property-value</lib:MyOtherProperty>
        </a:anyType>
    </MyList>
</MyRoot>
```

I used the "Create Schema" menu option in Visual Studio to generate the XSD files, but the editor still shows this error for the `<a:anyType` element:

```
This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary:MyObject'
```

I tried editing the XSD file for the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" namespace, but so far I haven't been able to eliminate the error.  Here is that XSD file as Visual Studio produces it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary" />
    <xs:element name="anyType">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary" ref="q1:MyProperty" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you include your imported schema? http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary

Answer (score 1):

I'm making several assumptions here since you didn't provide all the files to diagnose the problem. I will include complete XSD files that you can use and test, and try to adapt to your problem.

I'll assume that you have a main schema like this one, which defines the elements that are in the default namespace of your instance (I'll call it `DataContract.xsd`):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyDomain"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyDomain"> 

    <xs:element name="MyRoot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="MyList"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="MyList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Based on the data you posted I also assume that your `anyType` element is based on an abstract type from which `MyObject` and `MyOtherObject` are both derived from. I called it `AbstractObject` in the example below (`MyLibrary.xsd`):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary"> 

    <xs:complexType name="AbstractObject" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Identifier" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyObject">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="AbstractObject">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="MyProperty" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyOtherObject">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="AbstractObject">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="MyOtherProperty" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

To allow those types to be used in your instance via `anyType` you can declare it as having the `AbstractObject` type (or whatever your supertype is called in your actual `MyLibrary` schema):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary">

    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary" schemaLocation="MyLibrary.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="anyType" type="q1:AbstractObject" />

</xs:schema>
```

Since both `MyObject` and `MyOtherObject` are derivated from `AbstractObject`, they can be used as types for `<anyType>`. The instance below will validate in this scenario:

```
<MyRoot 
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyDomain"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:lib="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary"
    i:schemaLocation="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyDomain DataContract.xsd
                      http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays SerializationArrays.xsd">

    <MyList xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:anyType i:type="lib:MyObject">
            <lib:Identifier>my-identifier</lib:Identifier>
            <lib:MyProperty>my-property-value</lib:MyProperty>
        </a:anyType>
        <a:anyType i:type="lib:MyOtherObject">
            <lib:Identifier>my-identifier</lib:Identifier>
            <lib:MyOtherProperty>my-other-property-value</lib:MyOtherProperty>
        </a:anyType>
    </MyList>
</MyRoot>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the last bit of your suggestion working.  First it says "The 'type' attribute is invalid - The value 'q1:MyObject' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:QName' - 'q1' is an undeclared prefix."  If I move the prefix onto the `xs:element` then it says "Type 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyLibrary:MyObject' is not declared" even though I did declare it.

Comment: It might be a syntax error (there are some syntax errors in the code you pasted - unmatching tags, for example). If the namespace and prefix are declared, there is no reason for the error to occur. It might be due to some other problem. I added an instance you can use as an example. Cut and paste the code of all schemas as they are here, and test it. Then you can at least start with a working example before adapting to your real-world problem.

Comment: I tested your full example and it works well together as you said. Thanks.  Looks like I oversimplified my code in the original question a bit too much.  Please see my update.

Comment: I edited the answer to match the changes in your question and made changes in all the files.

Comment: +1 This may be the piece I was missing.  I'll test it a bit later.  Thank you again.